# How do I migrate a multilingual site?

Tags: 8, migrations

I'm currently trying to migrate my Drupal 7 site, which has the Dutch language enabled, to Drupal 8. I have enabled the following modules as instructed in the docs: Configuration Translation, Content Translation, Interface Translation, Language. After running the migration, no nodes have been created on the Drupal 8 site. Moreover, the log contains lots of error messages similar to the ones underneath.

> Migration d7_node_complete:webform did not meet the requirements.
>   Missing migrations language. requirements: language.
>
> Operation on Node complete (Webform) failed

Am I doing something wrong? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that some of the migration processes were stuck after the first attempt. Here is how I solved the problem and completed the migration of my multilingual site:

- Download and enable the [Migrate Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_tools) module and Drush 8
- Run `drush help` to verify that new migration commands such as `migrate-status` and `migrate-import` are enabled
- Run `drush migrate-status` and check the migration processes; all statusses should be *Idle*, but in my case some were stuck on *Importing*
- Use `migrate-stop` to stop any running processes; according to the documentation, this ''cleanly stops a running operation''
- Use `migrate-reset-status` to set the status of stopped processes back to *Idle*; according to the documentation, this ''sets a migration status to Idle if it's gotten stuck''
- Continue the upgrade via the [web browser](https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrade-using-web-browser) or [Drush](https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrade-using-drush)